# Difference between passing as int and the pointer inside class gives me segmentation fault

Tags: c++

I am trying to implement a simple linkedlist insertion in C++. Now, my code looks like in the first attempt, the code itself is self-explanatory but I have added some obvious comment as stackoverflow is not allowing me to post the question without putting some comments:

```
// Simple class and struct node
struct node {
        int data;
        struct node *next;
};

class list {
     // Member functions
     private:
        // Defining struct object
        node *root;

    public:
        bool insertNode(node *root); // Insertion function
        void print_list();
};

bool list::insertNode(node *n){
    root->next = n;
    return true;
    /*  
     node *temp = new node; 
     temp->data = data;

    if(root == NULL){
        root->next = new node;`enter code here`
        root->next->data = data;
        root->next->next = NULL;
        cout << "Coming" << "\n";
        return true;
    } else {
        temp->next = root;
        root = temp;
        return true;
    } */

}


void list::print_list(){

    node *p = root;
    // . Iterating the list
    p = p->next;
    while(p != NULL){
        cout << p->data << "\n";
        p = p->next;
    }
}

int main(){

    class list l;
    node *n = new node;
    n->data = 5;
    n->next = NULL;
    if(!l.insertNode(n)){
        cout << "Failed" << "\n";
        return 1;
    }
    l.print_list();

    return 1;
}
```

The thing is that when i try to modify my program as below, difference is that instead of having a node as argument in insert function, if I have an int as argument then it gives me segmentation fault.
==========================================================================

## include

```
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct node {
        int data;
        struct node *next;
};

class list {

     private:
        node *root;

    public:
        bool insertNode(int data);
        void print_list();
};

// Insertion function
bool list::insertNode(int data){

    if(root == NULL){
        root = new node; 
        root->data = data;
        root->next = NULL;
        return true;
    } else {
        node *temp = new node; 
        temp->data = data;
        temp->next = root;
        root = temp;
        return true;
    } 

    return false;
}

// Print function
void list::print_list(){

    node *p = root;

    p = p->next;
    while(p != NULL){
        cout << p->data << "\n";
        p = p->next;
    }
}

// Main driver code
int main(){

    class list l;
    
    if(!l.insertNode(5)){
        cout << "Failed" << "\n";`enter code here`
        return 1;
    }
    l.print_list();

    return 1;
}
```

output:./p

```
5
0
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Which means that in insertion function I pass an integer instead of a node then why I get segmentation fault? Since `root` defined in the list class has never been allocated memory and in my insertion function if I detect that root is null so I simply do `root = new node;` whats wrong with it? On the other hand if I insert a node instead of "int" in the insertion function then I get correct output? What is the difference?

Comment: in second code u define function with `bool list::insertNode(node *n)` but the prototype in the class is  `bool insertNode(int data);` so it shouldn't even compile because there is no function declaration in the class for the int version

Comment: please fix the code, as shown here it does not produce a seg fault but [a couple of compiler errors](http://ideone.com/uyFH6c)

Comment: Is it related to constructor and destructor?

Comment: I tried to change the code but some errors if I fix then stackoverflow isnt allowing me to post the question :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a list to work at all, it needs to be initialized properly.  You have a naked pointer, yet you do not have a contructor.  You do not have a destructor, either.

```
class list 
{
    private:
        node *root;

    public:
        List() { root = NULL; }
        ~List() { clear(); }

        void clear()
        {
            node *p = root, *q;
            while (p)
            {
               q = p->next;
               delete p;
               p = q;
            }
            root = NULL;
        }

        bool insertNode(node* p)
        {
            if (!p)
               return false;

            p->next = root;
            root = p;
            return true;
        }

        bool insertNode(int data)
        {
            node* p = new node;
            if (!p)
               return false;
            p->data = data;
            return insertNode(p);
        }
        // ...
};
```

Comment: Can you please explain the naked pointer thing? I got the constructor and destructor part.

Comment: node* is a naked pointer...  Modern C++ coding practice has banned them, more or less.  Their presence usually means that you are responsible for resource allocation and restitution.  They are now being wrapped by std::unique_ptr, shared_ptr and stl containers.  There actually is a list container in the stl, that modern practice says you should use instead of making your own. Using RAII techniques for coding in C++ really do make a difference.  I can't remember when I last had a memory leak.  Check the cppcon and boostcon videos on youtube for details.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Indeed I see the issue now. I shouldnt use naked pointer instead use smart pointer.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out the solution. It was indeed the constructor and destructor like Michael pointed out. In order to use the "root" I needed to initialize it and then I can use it for new and delete. Initialization and deletion should be in constructor and destructor. Complete code is below, please comment if you see any wrongdoing.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct node {
        int data;
        struct node *next;
};

class list {

     private:
        node *root;

    public:
        list(); // Default constructor
        ~list(); // Default destructor;

        bool insertNode(int data);
        bool remove(int data);
        void print_list();
};


list::list(void){
     root = NULL;

}

list::~list(void){

      node *p;
      while(root != NULL){
            p = root;
            root = root->next;
            free(p);
      }
}

bool list::remove(int data){

     node *p = root, *prev;
     while(p != NULL){
           if(p->data == data){
              prev->next = p->next;
              delete p;
              return true;
           }
           prev = p;
           p = p->next;
     }

     return false;
}

bool list::insertNode(int data){

    if(root == NULL){
        root = new node;
        root->data = data;
        root->next = NULL;
        return true;
    } else {
        node *temp = new node;
        temp->data = data;
        temp->next = root;
        root = temp;
        return true;
    }

}

void list::print_list(){

    node *p = root;

    while(p != NULL){
        cout << p->data << "\n";
        p = p->next;
    }
}

int main(){

    class list l;
    node *n = new node;
    n->data = 5;
    n->next = NULL;
    if(!l.insertNode(5)){
        cout << "Failed" << "\n";
        return 1;
    }
    l.insertNode(6);
    l.insertNode(7);
    cout << "Before deletion" << "\n";
    l.print_list();
    cout << "After deletion" << "\n";
    l.remove(5);
    l.print_list();

    return 1;
}
```